# Switching to devise for authentication, trying to update my user spec to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

Originally I had begun by building authentication from scratch using `bcrypt-ruby`, and had a working Rspec user model to test that the user could be found in the db with a valid password. Since then I've decided to instead go with Devise, but unfortunately now my spec is failing since I'm not using `has_secure_password` anymore in my User model, so the `authenticate` method is undefined. From what I've found by searching the devise wiki it seems like this may be more suited for a controller spec by using devise helpers but I'm confused as I just want to check the model as I was doing before to ensure the user can be authenticated and not entirely sure what to replace `authenticate` with.

My `user_spec.rb` file previously passing when I was using bcrypt with `has_secure_password`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    before { user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { found_user.authenticate(user.password).should eq user }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I would just delete this test - devise itself already has good test coverage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [devise rspec documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29) - there are a few helpers you'll want to set up in order to authenticate a user and perform tasks as a logged in user.

I wouldn't worry too much about testing the actual authentication logic - this should be covered by the spec tests within the devise gem itself.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. The specs you mention within the devise gem itself, I'm guessing those are mostly used for developing and contributing to the devise code, or do those specs need to be run as part of a regular test suite? (Such as what I was trying to do above with the authentication logic)

Comment: Those are for the gem themselves.  If you're just using the standard authentication provided by devise and not modifying it, I wouldn't worry about writing tests for it.  But if you modify the flow, your changes would be worth testing to a) make sure they work and b) make sure you don't break anything critical for the gem itself.